# Compute average value of items (elements) in FilteredList

Tags: java, list, javafx, average

Let's assume I have a simple application written in JavaFX.
It has a TableView with two columns, one with elements' names and other with elements' values.

Now I want compute average value of items that are visible in TableView, and update it every time elements are filtered by name.

This is what I already have:

```
@FXML  
public void filterProducts() {

    filteredProducts = new FilteredList<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(mainApp.getProductList()), p -> true);

    filterBtn.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        filteredProducts.setPredicate(product -> {
            return checkFilteringForNetPrice(product) && checkFilteringForManufacturer(product);
        });
    });


    SortedList<Product> sortedProducts = new SortedList<>(filteredProducts);
    sortedProducts.comparatorProperty().bind(productTable.comparatorProperty());
    productTable.setItems(sortedProducts);

    computeAverageAfterFiltering(sortedProducts);
}
```

With call for `computeAverageAfterFiltering(sortedProducts)` method I have been trying to compute average value of `sortedProducts` elements, but it contains exactly the same number of elements as `mainApp.getProductList()`.
I expected to find only filtered and sorted elements in `sortedProducts`.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only applying the filter when the button is pressed; however you are invoking the method `computeAverageAfterFiltering` immediately, i.e. before the filter is applied.

You can maintain the average of the elements in the filtered list with a binding:

```
DoubleBinding average = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> computeAverage(sortedProducts),
    sortedProducts);
```

The first argument to `createDoubleBinding` is the function that evaluates the binding, and the second is a list of objects to observe for changes. In this case we just pass the sorted list, so any time the list contents change, the binding is recomputed.

Then you can do things like

```
Label averageLabel = new Label();
averageLabel.textProperty().bind(average.asString("Average price: %f"));
```

with

```
private double computeAverage(List<Product> products) {
    return products.stream()
           // adjust Product::getPrice to give the values you want to average:
           .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Product::getPrice));
}
```